# Extra author appearing in biblatex-apa (as if two publications with the same first author appeared in the same year)

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm using biblatex v2.5 and the biblatex-apa style v5.7.

I have a couple citations with the same first author, including one with six co-authors in 2008. This is the *only publication* with that first author that was published in 2008, so it should just show up as **Ranney, et al. (2008)** - at least as I understand APA guidelines (section 6.12 / p. 175 in my 6th ed. copy).

biblatex is instead printing it as **Ranney, Rinne, et al. (2008)**, which I assume is to avoid ambiguous author lists. But again, I *think* this should only happen when you have the same first author on two pubs in a given year. This happens with `\nptextcite` and `\textcite`.

The extra weird thing is that *other* citations with this first author work out fine. For example, I have two pubs (with the same author list) correctly typesetting as **Ranney, et al. (2012a)** (and 2012b). But there are other cites with the same problem as well (e.g., **Ranney, Cheng, et al., 2001**, or **Munnich, Ranney, Nelson, et al. (2003)**).

So, I'm happy to do some hunting and hacking, but I'm not really sure where to start. In other words, please provide a partial answer even if you don't figure this one out!

(I also actually *like* the way biblatex is doing it, as I realize it helps me find references more easily. But it's not APA 6e per my reading.)

Comment: I will look at this if you can include a minimal .bib in your question with all of the mentioned entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, I had misread APA 6th edition 6.12. I will release an updated APA style shortly. In the interim, try setting the "uniquelist" option to biblatex to "minyear" as this option is explicitly designed to just exactly what the APA requires. I agree it's not so clear as cross-year name list disambiguation makes much more sense but APA 6th is explicit about it only being within the same year.

```
\usepackage[style=apa,uniquelist=minyear]{biblatex}
```

Comment: APA style version 6.1 has been released with this fix.

Comment: My slow response appears to have resulted in the problem being solved anyway... As it is, I'll accept this answer and not bother with the example. Let me know if you would somehow like example files!