# Biber doesn't work anymore (with biblatex-apa in TeXnicCenter)

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber, apa-style, texniccenter

Today I encountered an [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124733/34092) with `biblatex` and it seemed I had to update the `biblatex` package to the newest version to fix this.

So I went for a complete update of my MikTeX installation (installed all possible package updates... maybe that was a mistake, dunno). I knew I needed the newest `biber` (1.7) then, so I downloaded that. Log says `biblatex` is v2.7a. On the way I also updated to the newest `apa6.cls` and to TeXnicCenter 2.02 stable (32-bit on Win 7, used a beta before).

Before doing all this stuff, everything compiled properly... but now I get these Warnings like citation undefined... empty bibliography, undefined references etc. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Here is my TeXnicCenter config of biber:

[image]

Here is the working example, notice that I got `backend=biber`:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle,longtable]{apa6} % 12 pt., doppelter Zeilenabstand usw.

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % für ä,ö,ü,Ä,Ö,Ü,ß usw.

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % für exakte Darstellung von Umlauten wie Ä

\usepackage{lipsum}           % Dummy-Text
\setlipsumdefault{8}          % Standard-Einstellung: Verwendung nur eines Lipsum-Paragraphs (in diesem Fall des achten)

\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}      % linksbündige Tabellen (longtable)

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{textgreek}        % griechische Buchstaben im Text-Modus

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ von apa6.cls automatisch geladene Packages
% booktabs, etoolbox, lmodern, threeparttable



%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Scriptsize (ca. 8pt) Für Anmerkungen in Tabellen
\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro\TPT@defaults{\scriptsize} 
\makeatother
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Bibliographie/Biblatex/Literatur
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{             % ändert den Titel des LV von Literatur in Literaturverzeichnis
  references = {Literaturverzeichnis}
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%            % ändert "u. a." in "et al."
  andothers ={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  andmore   ={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}                   % lädt LV-Datei

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% Hier werden die (Unter-)Überschriften neu definiert (d. h. nicht fett usw.)

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}
  {\z@}
  {\b@level@one@skip}
  {\e@level@one@skip}
  {\centering\normalfont\normalsize}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}
  {\z@}
  {\b@level@two@skip}
  {\e@level@two@skip}
  {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
  {\z@}
  {\b@level@two@skip}
  {\e@level@two@skip}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\parindent}%
  {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\addperi}}
\makeatother

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%+++ TITELBLATT
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\title{title}
\shorttitle{shorttitle}
\renewcommand{\rheadname}{Kolumnentitel}     % Running head übersetzt

\author{\null C A}     
\affiliation{
\null
Universität 

Fachbereich 

Institut

Fachgebiet
}

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%+++ ZUSAMMENFASSUNG / ABSTRACT
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\abstract{\noindent 
\textit{Theoretischer Hintergrund:}

\textit{Fragestellung:}

\textit{Methode:}

\textit{Ergebnisse:}

\textit{Schlussfolgerungen:}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\clearpage
\section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}
\textit{Background:}

\textit{Objective:}

\textit{Methods:}

\textit{Results:}

\textit{Conclusions:}
\par
\end{otherlanguage}
}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\abstractname}{Zusammenfassung}{}{} % Umbenennen des ersten Abstracts in "Zusammenfassung" mit Paket etoolbox

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{.1\textheight}             % Vertikaler Abstand zum oberen Seitenrand

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%+++ Deckblatt
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\begin{center}
Title

\null
Wissenschaftliche Arbeit 

\null
Universität 

Fachbereich 

Fachgebiet 

\null
vorgelegt von

\null
C A

\null
\selectlanguage{ngerman}Bla, den \today
\end{center}
\pagestyle{otherpage}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}\maketitle             % Einfügen der Titelseite

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%+++ EINLEITUNG
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\section{Einleitung}

\lipsum

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%+++ METHODE
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\newpage{\section{Methode}}


\subsection{Überblick}

\lipsum


\subsection{Stichprobe}


\subsection{Material}


\subsubsection{Stimulusmaterial}


\paragraph{Wortpaare}

\lipsum


\subsubsection{Geräte/Apparaturen}


\subsubsection{Aufgabe}

\lipsum

\subsubsection{Fragebögen}


\paragraph{Index}

\lipsum


\paragraph{Screening}

\lipsum


\paragraph{Inventory}

\lipsum

\cite{MacLeodetal2002}

\subsubsection{Übungen}

\lipsum


\subsection{Versuchsablauf}

\lipsum


%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%+++ ERGEBNISSE
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\newpage{\section{Ergebnisse}}


%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%+++ DISKUSSION
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\newpage{\section{Diskussion}}


%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%+++ Literatur
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\printbibliography



\end{document}
```

Edit: The .bib content I am citing in this example:

```
@article{MacLeodetal2002,
    author={Colin MacLeod and Elizabeth Rutherford and Lyn Campbell and Greg Ebsworthy and Lin Holker},
    year={2002},
    title={Selective attention and emotional vulnerability: Assessing the causal basis of their association through the experimental manipulation of attentional bias},
    journal={Journal of Abnormal Psychology},
    volume={111},
    number={1},
    pages={107-123},
}
```

Edit2: I don't know if this is helping... the biber log:

[image]

Comment: Can you report the contents of the `.blg` file the run of Biber produces?

Comment: How do you open a .blg? Windows says it is a "performance monitoring" file ("Leistungsüberwachung" in german) which is usually opened with something like a monitoring program. But nothing can be seen there. If I open it with TeXnicCenter there is only: "[0] Config.pm:425> INFO - This is Biber 1.7
[1] Config.pm:428> INFO - Logfile is 'Arbeit.blg'"

Comment: solved - I will create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you find the solution not until having posted a question...

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93997/34092) was the solution (the bottom part of the answer about biber's temp cache).